# driver.close() does not close the tab on selenium if I call it from an instance

Tags: python, selenium

I want to close the tab on Chrome which is opened from Selenium, but if I create an instance and call the `driver.close()` from the instance, it does not close the tab. For example,

```
class Download:

    def __init__(self, word, driver):
        self.word = word
        self.word_url = word_url_meta.format(word)
        self.driver = driver


    def close_tab(self):
        self.switch_window(self.current_window)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        self.driver.close()
        time.sleep(0.2)
        self.switch_window(self.driver.window_handles[-1])

    def switch_window(self):  
        time.sleep(0.2) 
        self.driver.switch_to_window(self.current_window)
```

Then, I call it as:

```
w = Download()
w.do_something()
w.close_tab()
```

If I call it from the top level, the tab closes properly. But when I call it from an instance method, the tab does not close.

Why does it prevent the tab from being closed? And how can I close it properly?

---

#### EDIT

Now I might wonder it is because wrap it with `asyncio`.

```
async def download_word(word, driver, semaphore):
    async with semaphore:
        w = Download(word, driver)
        w.open_new_tab()
        await w.check_if_downloadable()
        await w.download()
        w.close_tab()

async def main():
    asyncio_semaphore = asyncio.BoundedSemaphore(2)
    jobs = []
    for i in range(4):
        jobs.append(asyncio.ensure_future(download_word(words[i], driver, asyncio_semaphore)))
    await asyncio.gather(*jobs)

loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Is it relevant here?

Comment: What is `self.current_window`? Also let us know how did you create `Download()` instance without passing any arguments

Comment: @Andersson Sorry I forgot to add the method, but it is simply calling the window moving method of the driver.

Comment: Why is the question considered unclear on what I'm asking...?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you did anything wrong. Just tried your code with a slight modification and it works for me:

```
word = None
import time

class Download:

    def __init__(self, word, driver):
        self.word = word
        self.driver = driver
        self.driver.get(word)     
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.execute_script("window.open('" + word + "', 'new_window')")
        time.sleep(2)

    def close_tab(self):
        self.driver.close()
        time.sleep(2)
```

And the test:

```
class TestCloseTab:    

    def test_close_tab(self):
        download = Download('http://testjs.site88.net/', pytest.driver)
        download.close_tab()
```